# Player's Dash abilty not isnt working correctly

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics

I don't know how to make my character dash without it keeps ignoring the cooldown and the dash distance is small. I have been stumped on this for a long time and i want to continue with other things in my game but this has been stopping me. I use Unity and C#.

Here's my code:

```
public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private BoxCollider2D bc;

    private static bool isRunning;
    private static bool isMoving;
    private static bool isDashing; 
    private static bool isOnWall;
    private static bool cooldown;
    private static bool jumpCooldown;
    
   
    private float time = 4f;
    private float dashingspeed = 14f;
    private float timewhiledashing = 2f;
    private Vector2 dashingDir;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        bc = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        cooldown = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        bool IsGrounded()
        {
            float extraHeightText = .01f;
            RaycastHit2D raycastHit = Physics2D.Raycast(bc.bounds.center, Vector2.down, bc.bounds.extents.y + extraHeightText);
            Color rayColor;
            if (raycastHit.collider != null)
            {
                rayColor = Color.green;
            } 
            else
            {
                rayColor = Color.red;
            }
            Debug.DrawRay(bc.bounds.center, Vector2.down * (bc.bounds.extents.y + extraHeightText));
            return raycastHit.collider != null;
        }
        
        
        float dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * 4f, rb.velocity.y);
        isMoving = true;
        
        float dirY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        
          


        if (Input.GetKey("left ctrl"))
        isRunning = true;
        else
        {
            isRunning = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("left shift") && cooldown == false)
        isDashing = true;
        else
        {
            isDashing = false;
        }

        if (IsGrounded() && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 8f);
        }
        

       if (isRunning == true && isMoving == true)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * 6f, rb.velocity.y);
        }

        if (isDashing == true && cooldown == false)
        {
            
            dashingDir = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
            if (dashingDir == new Vector2(0f,0f))
            {
                dashingDir = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x, 0f);
            }
            
        }
         
        
        if (isDashing == true)
        {
            rb.velocity = dashingDir.normalized * dashingspeed;
            return;
        }

         if (isDashing == true)
        {
            timewhiledashing -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
        }


        if (timewhiledashing == 0f)
        {
            cooldown = true;
        }
        

        if (IsGrounded())
        {
            cooldown = false;
        }
        

       if (cooldown == true)
        {
            isDashing = false;
            time -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
        }

       if (time == 0f)
       {
        cooldown = false;
        time = 4f;
        timewhiledashing = 2f;
       }


    } 
}
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is of course in `c#`

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not dashing is because it detects if you get the key down, and if not it will be true again. So if you press the key, it will be true, then next frame it will be false.

This way, time while dashing will only go down for **one frame.**

Instead, you should use

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
```